# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: multi-sites, database

have transferred a Drupal multi-site configuration to a new server with the intent to separate the two websites into individual Drupal installations.

I receive the following error from Drupal:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Invalid argument in
>   lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of
>   /home/designglassco/public_html/drupal/includes/lock.inc).

Most of the internet seems to point to a database issue but I have triple checked this information and all is fine.

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'DB_NAME',
      'username' => 'DB_USER',
      'password' => 'DB_PASSWORD',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'unix_socket' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1.

I am using Drupal 7.34, PHP 5.4.27, and MySQL 5.5.40.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What version of Drupal is it? Exactly? And what are the versions of both PHP and MySQL? On the source and on the destination server? And have you tried setting host to 127.0.0.1? Sometimes localhost fails to resolve. Shouldn't, but I've seen it happening.

Comment: Drupal ver 7.34. PHP ver 5.4.27. MySQL ver 5.5.40. Unfortunately I don't know the versions on the source server as my client has fallen out with the previous company and we can't contact them.

Comment: Please edit details like that directly into the question.

Comment: I suspect the DB host should be different than localhost. if your database is still on the old server than you should put the IP of that server.

Comment: I have been given a dump of the database and I've imported this into my server.

Comment: dump can go wrong check if your database is up and available, 
on your terminal type this command

`mysql -u DB_NAME -pDB_PASSWORD`

Comment: The database is running perfectly fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error on my local MAMP: PDOException: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\]](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146331/error-on-my-local-mamp-pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002)